# How to maintain a constant number of PEDESTRIANS in SUMO

Tags: veins, sumo

I am using SUMO 0.30.0 and I want to simulate an scenario with a constant number of pedestrians walking on the streets. I checked SUMO's FAQ, specifically [How do I generate random routes?](https://sumo.dlr.de/docs/FAQ.html#How_do_I_maintain_a_constant_number_of_vehicles_in_the_net.3F) and I managed to maintain a constant number of vehicles using rerouters or the --max-num-vehicles option in the sumo.cfg file. However, rerouters are not yet implemented for persons in SUMO.

Is there any way of maintain a fixed number of pedestrians?

I want to use this scenario with Veins and OMNeT++, so maybe there's a way of maintaint the number of pedestrians using Veins (?)

Comment: Is updating SUMO an option? The support for remote controlling pedestrians is very limited in 0.30.0.

Comment: Sadly no, I have to use that version because of compatibility issues with other projects.

Comment: Can you send them on a very long circular route or do they need to behave somehow random or according to a defined demand?

Comment: I'm using a kind of a typical Manhattan scenario, with a few blocks. I solved the problem of vehicles using rerouters. However, in the version of SUMO that I'm using persons do not care about the rerouters

Comment: Yes, but you could give the persons long routes with repeating edges manually.

Comment: That sounds interesting, but sorry, I did not understand how I could do something like that. Could you please elaborate on that?

Comment: I manage to implement what you said about generating long routes. I used randomtrips.py with the --intermediate attribute using (without establishing the person type) and then I edited the .rou.xml file to be a person file